# На некоторых устройствах вылезает android.view.InflateException

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение в Google Play. В последнее время приходит вот такая ошибка:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:309)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:354)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:223)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:242)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:551)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:429)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:380)
  at ml.bakhanov.schoolmosreg.SchoolAPI.setUpDialog (SchoolAPI.java:152)
  at ml.bakhanov.schoolmosreg.SchoolAPI.showPasswordChanged (SchoolAPI.java:145)
  at ml.bakhanov.schoolmosreg.SchoolAPI.login (SchoolAPI.java:622)
  at ml.bakhanov.schoolmosreg.SchoolAPI.loginCookies (SchoolAPI.java:694)
  at ml.bakhanov.schoolmosreg.SchoolAPI.getWeek (SchoolAPI.java:1977)
  at ml.bakhanov.schoolmosreg.TimeTableNotification$NotificationsTask.doInBackground (TimeTableNotification.java:51)
  at ml.bakhanov.schoolmosreg.TimeTableNotification$NotificationsTask.doInBackground (TimeTableNotification.java:29)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:295)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:657)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:776)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:716)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:847)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:855)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:527)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Native Method)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:631)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme (ThemeUtils.java:33)
  at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init> (TextInputLayout.java:190)
  at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init> (TextInputLayout.java:183)
```

Происходит в последней строке вот этого кода:

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.password_changed_alert, null);
```

Код password_changed_alert:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/password_has_been_changed_alert_message"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/alert_login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/alert_login_form">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/alert_loginInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/passwordInputLayout"
            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/passwordInputLayout"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/passwordInputLayout"
            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/passwordInputLayout">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/alert_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_login"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/captcha"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/captcha"
                android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/captcha" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/alert_passwordInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/alert_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/alert_captchaImage"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder_captcha"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/alert_captchaInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/alert_captcha"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/enter_captcha"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Самое интересное, что ошибка происходит только на устройствах с версией Android 6.0. Вот список некоторых из них: Samsung Galaxy A5 (a5lte), HTC One M9 (htc_himaulatt), LGE LG X power (mk6p), Lenovo TAB 10 (TB-X103F), BlackBerry PRIV by BlackBerry (venice) и др.

Comment: target sdk какой? И какая тема используется?

Comment: похоже что-то с темой, да) начальная ошибка `IllegalArgumentException` `.checkAppCompatTheme`, остальные производные от нее